# Entity Framework SelectMany ignoring Where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity hierarchy such as: `parent` => `child` => `grandchildren`.

I have the `parent` entity loaded, now I need to do a group-by select of the grandchildren with a where-clause on the grand-children.

The query I'm trying is essentially:

```
parent.Children
    .SelectMany(c => c.GrandChildren.Where(g=>g.BooleanField)) // try here
    .Where(g => g.BooleanField) // and try here
    .GroupBy(g => new { Name = g.FullName })
    .Select(m => new
    {
        m.Key.Name,
        Amount = m.Sum(o => o.DecimalField)
    })
    .OrderBy(m => m.Name);
```

The `BooleanField` filter is not being applied, though - I can see this from a SQL trace. I have it in two places, why is it not filtering?

#### Edit

The actual entities are projects, milestones and times. Here is a screenshot of the entity framework code at the top, and the outputted TSQL beneath in the Output window. You can clearly see I have both `WHERE` clauses in place but the TSQL doesn't include the IsBillable field at all.

[image]

Comment: You are basically telling us that `Where` doesn't work. Since that's not true it's difficult to help without more informations.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't know what else to give you? Here's a screenshot showing the actual outputs exactly as I explained.

Comment: @Dennis It's doing the ID lookup on the milestone, I presume because that project only has one milestone, so it's worked that out and is passing it in as a parameter (EntityKeyValue1). But that's the exact SQL that's being generated.

Comment: `consultants.ToString()` gives me `System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable'2[<>f__AnonymousType35'3[System.String,System.Decimal,System.Decimal],System.String]`

Comment: @Sean: oops. I've thought for some reason, that project is `IQueryable`. Posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `project` is some entity instance, and you're using lazy loading, then SQL from output is OK, because filtering and grouping is being performed at client side. EF can't filter child entities in this case using SQL query.

The only query against database here is a query, that loads `Times` of the particular `Milestone`:

```
project
    .Milestones // this is loaded already for some reason
    .SelectMany(m => m.Times /* this causes lazy loading and SQL in output */ 
        .Where(...) // from here everything is being executed in memory)
    .Where(...)
    ...
```

Comment: Would eager loading the children + grandchildren help then?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: eager loading can't filter related entities too, but explicit loading - can: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I suppose going the iQueryable route is simply better though? Tried that and it's working with the clause in place, I assume it's just a better way to do it too.

Comment: @Sean: If collections contains significant amount of records, then yes, `IQueryable` + database is usually a better choice, than in-memory manipulations.